# MVC Controller initializer is being called many times

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unity-container

**The problem:**

When I'm loading my application is trying to initialize the main controller many times and I would like to know why... that's making me crazy, If one of us had a similar error and want to give me trips about what I have to check, I'll be agreed!!.

MVC3 C# Using Unity as IoC

*Controller:*

```
    public ValorationController(IServiceProxy serviceProxy, 
                                IHvmService hvmService, 
                                IFamilyGroupService familyGroupService, 
                                IClientService clientService,
                                IUserService userService,
                                IOfficeService delegationService,
                                ISocietyService societyService,
                                IFamilyService familyService,
                                IArticleService articleService,
                                IArticleFinishedService articleFinishedService,
                                IOrderService orderService)
        : base(serviceProxy)
    {
        FamilyService = familyService;
        ArticleService = articleService;
        HvmService = hvmService;
        FamilyGroupService = familyGroupService;
        ClientService = clientService;
        UserService = userService;
        DelegationService = delegationService;
        SocietyService = societyService;
        ArticleFinishedService = articleFinishedService;
        OrderService = orderService;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, but this doesn't explain the problem you seem to have. When is the main controller being initialized? Why do you think it is initialized many times? Why do you think it is incorrect?

Comment: Will need to include even more detail than that

Comment: The main controller is being initialized on Register Route by default, I thought that was for CSS, and HTML errors like crashed links... but I checked that and I couldn't find the error...

Answer (score 2):

Your controller will be initialized on every *request* that involves it.

This is normal and how IIS works.

Comment: Hi Oded, ty for your fast response I'm executing only One Action(one request) the default on RegisterRoutes. How could I check all requests that are executing my controller ? in order to check that error I was looking on fiddler, but I can't find it

Comment: @user1520494 - Then how did you determine that the controller was initialized multiple times? How do you know?

Comment: Because I'm fixing a breakPoint on the controller and Stopped 14 times before show Main view

Comment: I have removed all parameters on my controller constructor, and still doing the same...

Comment: @user1520494 - Great. Did you look at the stack trace for these 14 times? That will tell you what is calling the controller.

Comment: I Checked but I'm getting that's called from External Code without more information,

Comment: @user1520494 - It is impossible to help with the information you have provided.

Comment: @user1520494: Disable Just My Code in debugger options.

Answer (score 0):

Also good to know that every `Unity` `Resolve` will create by default a new `instance`. If you do not want that, you should provide a `LifeTimeManager`

Read Microsoft's articles about [Understanding Lifetime Managers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660872%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx) and [Using Lifetime Managers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647854.aspx).

Maybe you want to use something like this:

```
// Register a default (un-named) type mapping with a singleton lifetime 
myContainer.RegisterType<IMyObject, MySingletonObject>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
// Following code will return a singleton instance of MySingletonObject// Container will take over lifetime management of the object
myContainer.Resolve<IMyObject>();
```